# Get last 1st November date

Tags: php

I am trying to get the last 1st November date based on today's date.

E.g. today is 2016-09-23 so the last 1st November would be 2015-11-01.

If today's date is 2016-11-20 the last 1st November would be 2016-11-01.

I have the following code which just pulls the 1st November of the current year.

```
$last_november = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('1st november'));
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this :

```
$date = date('Y-m-d');
$lastNovember = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('1st november'));
$year = '';
//decrement the year's value by 1 to get previous year november's first date
if ($date < $lastNovember) {
  $year = date('Y') - 1;
  $lastNovember = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("1st november {$year}"));
}

var_dump($lastNovember);
```

i.e, use previous year if current date is less than this year's Nov's date

Answer (score 1):

All we need to know is if the current date is before or after 1st November. If we are before 1st November then the last 1st November was last year, otherwise it was this year (including if today is 1st November).

```
$year = date('Y'); // start with the current year

if (date('nd') < 1101) {
    // we are before 1st November so the last one was last year
    $year--;
}

$last_november = $year . '-11-01';
```

or if you want it all in one line,

```
$last_november = (date('nd') < 1101 ? (date('Y')-1) : date('Y')) . '-11-01';
```

**Note:**
A potential gotcha is how you write the date in the comparison `(date('nd') < 1101)`. Match the date format `nd`. Write the month without any leading 0's but always write the day as two characters (with a leading 0 if needed). 1st January is `101`, 20 January is `120`, 17 November is `1117` etc... See http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php